# Antivirus logging to Windows Event Viewer

Tags: windows, anti-virus, logging, event-viewer

I'm trying to find antivirus software with centralized management that logs 'everything' to Windows Event Viewer (or a text file). It will run in a server environment. I'm talking about these kinds of logs:
- got update
- started scanning
- threat found - action taken

... and other types of text logs that might come in handy at a later point if an audit is being performed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What security software have you seen that doesn't do this?

Comment: I have tried Trend Micro Worry-Free Business Security. There it doesn't log in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Your question originally asked specifically for one that logs to the Windows events log and  Microsoft Security Essentials seems to do this. You need to filter the **System** log by Event Source: **Microsoft Antimalware**

[image: Event source]

This is what is shows on my PC:

[image: Log]

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that it will need centralized management because it will be run in a multiple server environment.

Answer (score 0):

Kaspersky does this, if you buy the Enterprise version.  It logs to both the central console (from where it's managed) as well as event viewer on the local machine.  Last time I looked, Symantec's enterprise version also did this. http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH186925 seems to say so, but I can't find an image or much info.

Actually Kaspersky createes it's own separate event log, but is available via the Event Viewer as well as the events being accessible centrally.

[image]